# CodeIgniter Fatal Error

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to use a script for a Bitcoin dice site and I think it uses **CodeIgniter**.
The problem is this error keeps coming up:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_DB_mysql6.000webhost.com_driver' not found in /home/forever/public_html/system/database/DB.php on line 144
```

Here is my `DB.php` file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Initialize the database
 *
 * @category    Database
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/
 * @param   string
 * @param   bool    Determines if active record should be used or not
 */
function &DB($params = '', $active_record_override = NULL)
{
    // Load the DB config file if a DSN string wasn't passed
    if (is_string($params) AND strpos($params, '://') === FALSE)
    {
        // Is the config file in the environment folder?
        if ( ! defined('ENVIRONMENT') OR ! file_exists($file_path = APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/database.php'))
        {
            if ( ! file_exists($file_path = APPPATH.'config/database.php'))
            {
                show_error('The configuration file database.php does not exist.');
            }
        }

        include($file_path);

        if ( ! isset($db) OR count($db) == 0)
        {
            show_error('No database connection settings were found in the database config file.');
        }

        if ($params != '')
        {
            $active_group = $params;
        }

        if ( ! isset($active_group) OR ! isset($db[$active_group]))
        {
            show_error('You have specified an invalid database connection group.');
        }

        $params = $db[$active_group];
    }
    elseif (is_string($params))
    {

        /* parse the URL from the DSN string
         *  Database settings can be passed as discreet
         *  parameters or as a data source name in the first
         *  parameter. DSNs must have this prototype:
         *  $dsn = 'driver://username:password@hostname/database';
         */

        if (($dns = @parse_url($params)) === FALSE)
        {
            show_error('Invalid DB Connection String');
        }

        $params = array(
                            'dbdriver'  => $dns['scheme'],
                            'hostname'  => (isset($dns['host'])) ? rawurldecode($dns['host']) : '',
                            'username'  => (isset($dns['user'])) ? rawurldecode($dns['user']) : '',
                            'password'  => (isset($dns['pass'])) ? rawurldecode($dns['pass']) : '',
                            'database'  => (isset($dns['path'])) ? rawurldecode(substr($dns['path'], 1)) : ''
                        );

        // were additional config items set?
        if (isset($dns['query']))
        {
            parse_str($dns['query'], $extra);

            foreach ($extra as $key => $val)
            {
                // booleans please
                if (strtoupper($val) == "TRUE")
                {
                    $val = TRUE;
                }
                elseif (strtoupper($val) == "FALSE")
                {
                    $val = FALSE;
                }

                $params[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    // No DB specified yet?  Beat them senseless...
    if ( ! isset($params['dbdriver']) OR $params['dbdriver'] == '')
    {
        show_error('You have not selected a database type to connect to.');
    }

    // Load the DB classes.  Note: Since the active record class is optional
    // we need to dynamically create a class that extends proper parent class
    // based on whether we're using the active record class or not.
    // Kudos to Paul for discovering this clever use of eval()

    if ($active_record_override !== NULL)
    {
        $active_record = $active_record_override;
    }

    require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB_driver.php');

    if ( ! isset($active_record) OR $active_record == TRUE)
    {
        require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB_active_rec.php');

        if ( ! class_exists('CI_DB'))
        {
            eval('class CI_DB extends CI_DB_active_record { }');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! class_exists('CI_DB'))
        {
            eval('class CI_DB extends CI_DB_driver { }');
        }
    }

    require_once(BASEPATH.'database/drivers/'.$params['dbdriver'].'/'.$params['dbdriver'].'_driver.php');

        // Instantiate the DB adapter
    $driver = 'CI_DB_'.$params['dbdriver'].'_driver';
    $DB = new $driver($params);

    if ($DB->autoinit == TRUE)
    {
        $DB->initialize();
    }

    if (isset($params['stricton']) && $params['stricton'] == TRUE)
    {
        $DB->query('SET SESSION sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"');
    }

    return $DB;
}



/* End of file DB.php */
/* Location: ./system/database/DB.php */
```

This is my `database.php` file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| DATABASE CONNECTIVITY SETTINGS
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file will contain the settings needed to access your database.
|
| For complete instructions please consult the 'Database Connection'
| page of the User Guide.
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| EXPLANATION OF VARIABLES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|   ['hostname'] The hostname of your database server.
|   ['username'] The username used to connect to the database
|   ['password'] The password used to connect to the database
|   ['database'] The name of the database you want to connect to
|   ['dbdriver'] The database type. ie: mysql.  Currently supported:
                 mysql, mysqli, postgre, odbc, mssql, sqlite, oci8
|   ['dbprefix'] You can add an optional prefix, which will be added
|                to the table name when using the  Active Record class
|   ['pconnect'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to use a persistent connection
|   ['db_debug'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether database errors should be displayed.
|   ['cache_on'] TRUE/FALSE - Enables/disables query caching
|   ['cachedir'] The path to the folder where cache files should be stored
|   ['char_set'] The character set used in communicating with the database
|   ['dbcollat'] The character collation used in communicating with the database
|                NOTE: For MySQL and MySQLi databases, this setting is only used
|                as a backup if your server is running PHP < 5.2.3 or MySQL < 5.0.7
|                (and in table creation queries made with DB Forge).
|                There is an incompatibility in PHP with mysql_real_escape_string() which
|                can make your site vulnerable to SQL injection if you are using a
|                multi-byte character set and are running versions lower than these.
|                Sites using Latin-1 or UTF-8 database character set and collation are unaffected.
|   ['swap_pre'] A default table prefix that should be swapped with the dbprefix
|   ['autoinit'] Whether or not to automatically initialize the database.
|   ['stricton'] TRUE/FALSE - forces 'Strict Mode' connections
|                           - good for ensuring strict SQL while developing
|
| The $active_group variable lets you choose which connection group to
| make active.  By default there is only one group (the 'default' group).
|
| The $active_record variables lets you determine whether or not to load
| the active record class
*/

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'blocked';
$db['default']['username'] = 'blocked';
$db['default']['password'] = 'blocked';
$db['default']['database'] = 'blocked';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


/* End of file database.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/database.php */
```

I blocked out my database details for personal reasons.

Comment: can u please provide the database.php file in config

Answer (score 1):

This is not your actual config/database.php file.
Your 'dbdriver' value is 'mysql6.000webhost.com' instead of 'mysql' - fix that.

Comment: Agreed. I would add that `mysql6.000webhost.com` is probably the hostname value instead